# How to add superscript in option tag select dropdown 1st 2nd 3rd 4th 5th. 1ST I want S captial letters but i tried s will converted to small case

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, laravel

[image: I w]

I used below code. But 1st --> returns 1sT --> I need 1ST

```
<option value="1ST"
                <?php if (in_array("1ST", $_POST['pay_day'])) echo selected; ?>
                > 1&#x02E2;&#x1D40;   </option>
            <option value="2ND"
                <?php if (in_array("2ND", $_POST['pay_day'])) echo selected; ?>
                > 2&#x1D3A;&#x1D30;  </option>
            <option value="3RD"
                <?php if (in_array("3RD", $_POST['pay_day'])) echo selected; ?>
                > 3&#x1D3F;&#x1D30;  </option>
            <option value="4TH"
                <?php if (in_array("4TH", $_POST['pay_day'])) echo selected; ?>
                > 4&#x1D40;&#x1D34; </option>
            <option value="5TH"
                <?php if (in_array("5TH", $_POST['pay_day'])) echo selected; ?>
                > 5&#x1D40;&#x1D34; </option>
```

Please help

Comment: I think we can do only with images with superscript

Answer (score 0):

```
<option value="1ST" <?php if (in_array("1ST", $_POST['pay_day'])) echo selected; ?> > 1<span style="text-transform: capitalize;">&#x02E2;&#x1D40;</span></option>
<option value="2ND" <?php if (in_array("2ND", $_POST['pay_day'])) echo selected; ?> > 2<span style="text-transform: capitalize;">&#x1D3A;&#x1D30;</span>  </option>
<option value="3RD" <?php if (in_array("3RD", $_POST['pay_day'])) echo selected; ?> > 3<span style="text-transform: capitalize;">&#x1D3F;&#x1D30;</span>  </option>
<option value="4TH" <?php if (in_array("4TH", $_POST['pay_day'])) echo selected; ?> > 4<span style="text-transform: capitalize;">&#x1D40;&#x1D34;</span> </option>
<option value="5TH" <?php if (in_array("5TH", $_POST['pay_day'])) echo selected; ?> > 5<span style="text-transform: capitalize;">&#x1D40;&#x1D34;</span> </option>
```